# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting error when i enter the URL "http://localhost:8090/hamropasal/" as it says that it doesnot found the mappings when i hit the URL.i have added all the dependency and the required beans but it is not working.I have tried to look error in my code but i didnot found what actual the problem is.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hamropasal/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

My web.xml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my dispatcher-servlet.xml is :

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 

   ">



<context:component-scan base-package="com.ashwin.hamropasal.*" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>



</beans>
```

PageController.java

```
package com.ashwin.hamropasal.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/","/home","/index"})
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("greetings","WELCOME TO SPRING");
        return mv;

    }

}
```

my pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ashwin</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamropasal</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hamropasal Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
  <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>hamropasal</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

[image: My project structure is]

Comment: Could you please access "http://localhost:8090/" or "http://localhost:8090/home" or "http://localhost:8090/index". "hamropasal" is neither found in method level nor in class level so you shouldn't use it in your URL

Comment: no it says http status 404error. project name should be given

Comment: I did faced the same issue several time. I follow the steps mentioned here:
https://coderwall.com/p/gbi7iw/complete-refresh-of-a-web-application-in-eclipse-for-java-using-tomcat